# How do I re-enable class verifiction on eclipse start-up

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I installed a plugin named, "Optimizer for Eclipse".

[image]

I clicked the **Disable verification** button.

This now doesn't allow me to run files without building the project.

Everytime I run a java project, If it is a new file. It says cannot find or load main class.

If I build the project and then run it runs.

If I change the file and again run it. It runs the previously compiled file.

How do I re-enable class verification in Eclipse?

Comment: check out the optimizer options?

Comment: Yes, No luck. There are no options to remove or anything. I uninstalled the plugin, no change still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suffered the same problem.

Go into your Eclipse folder, open `eclipse.ini` with your text editor.
Delete the following line:

```
-Xverify:none
```

Then, restart your IDE, the verification will come back.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the workspace works!

All the settings are gone in the new workspace and it's totally new.